# How to print entries from a dictionary without quotes and with a newline in between?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Title is pretty self-explanatory, it's late in the day and I know I'll fell dumb from how easy it is;)  Here is my code, I'm using `DictReader`.

```
for line in myreader:
    if prop_code == line['Property Code']:
        print('Property Code: %s\n' % line['Property Code'],
              'Pivot ID: %s\n' % line['Pivot ID'],
              'Inwork File: %s\n' % line['Inwork File'],
              'Billing Manager E-mail: %s\n' % line['Billing Manager E-mail'],
              'Total Records: %s\n' % line['Total Records'],
              'Number of E-Bills: %s\n' % line['Number of E-Bills'],
              'Printed Records: %s\n' % line['Printed Records'],
              'File Date: %s\n' % line['File Date'])
```

Comment: paste your sample dictionary. And please avoid terms like _Title is pretty self-explanatory, it's late in the day and I know I'll fell dumb from how easy it is;)_ . You should rather give more details on what you did and where you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sample = {'city': 'San Francisco', 2: 'Neato', 'name': 'Zed', 1: 'Wow', 'age': 39, 'height': 74}

for i in sample.keys():
    print '{} : {}\n'.format(i,sample.get(i))
```

Output:

```
city : San Francisco

2 : Neato

name : Zed

1 : Wow

age : 39

height : 74
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

Wrap each line inside a print

```
print('Property Code: %s' % line['Property Code'])
print('Pivot ID: %s' % line['Pivot ID']')
```

Or you can use pprint

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(line)
```